# Web Pages That Just Do Too Much Stuff

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, application-design

Concerning pages that build a web application:

Lately, I have found myself creating web pages that are simpler than the ones I used to. Before, I would try to jam as much functionality into a single page as I could to prevent from having lots of pages.

I am starting to realize that this was just making things way more complex, convoluted, and confusing than it had to be. Why not have more pages? I think the reason that I was doing this was because I didn't want the user to have to browse to other pages; just to have all the functionality they needed on a single page.

Well, these good intentions turned into an overly confusing interface for the user and very unmanageable source code. I am a new developer and I am trying to be very reflective of what I am doing so that I can improve. If it makes a difference, I am developing in ASP.net (though these are probably considerations for any platform).

My questions are:

- Am I overthinking these things?
- Has anyone else found themselves doing this?
- Where is the happy medium?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no expert who can give you a rule that works in all places at all times. I have been known in my industry for years for "easy" interfaces and we've won significant amounts of business for it (as well as 5 "Best in Class" awards). I have also had people within my company and outside of it tell me - for years - that they like my work but wish that I would "jazz it up" with more graphics and such.  What always amazes me is how little connection people see between the two.

So...a few rules of thumb:

1. A page should do one *main* thing.
2. A page may well have multiple links related to the main thing
3. Menuing and link layout should be consistent across pages
4. Simpler is better than more complex
5. Pages should be visually appealing and inviting
6. Rule 4 is more important than rule 5.

For example, my product provides an interface that lets people define classes and events to be displayed in a calendar.  I *could* have one page that lets you Review, Add, Update, Delete and Edit the classes.  Indeed, in some simpler areas, I've used the gridview to let people manage everything in a grid. However, classes have too much information to do this and still follow the rules above.

So,

1. The *main idea* is: "Here is a list of classes for this location"
2. The links are "Add New" shown above and to the right of the grid, Change and Delete are links within each row. This is consistent across the app.
3. Menuing for the system as a whole is always across the right/top. Nothing else appears on the class/event page except for standard elements common to all pages (a logo, a header, a footer).
4. The grid is nicely styled but there are no spurious graphics (4,5,6)

---

A few last things about UIs and graphic design.

First, develop your own vision and be consistent across pages and apps.

Second, do not be afraid of [simplicity](http://www.alistapart.com).

Next, when soliciting advice from others keep in mind that you do not want their advice - you want their impressions: you want to understand the way they *perceive* the interface.  Advice is sometimes good but, more often than not, actually harmful. In my experience, everyone thinks that they are a UI expert.

When you do your hallway (or formal) useability testing you should discount almost all advice to the effect that "you should make **that** stand out more."  As you'll see, it will quickly become "and **that**," "and **that**," "and **the other**."  If you follow this advice, you'll end up with a mess due to Brittingham's first rule of design: *If everything is important than nothing is.* (There you go: when explaining why you can't make someone stand out more, just tell them that "it violates Brittingham's first rule of design!")

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You hit the nail on the head. Use the KISS principle. (Keep It Simple Stupid)
I've done this in the past as well and not only does it make for a hideous UI, but confusing as to what operations you can do on the page due to having too much functionality. I've often found in testing that I did not have enough checks to see if the user could perform a certain operation based on the state of the data.

It's easy enough in ASP.Net to write several pages that do simple tasks and then link them together with Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer. Now all I try to achieve on any given page is what the design specs say. So if my page is just a search page, that's all I give. If the user wants to see the details of an item that was returned in the search, then I send them to an itemDetails.aspx page.

Comment: I agree. The only issue I have with multiple pages is saving and retrieving page data from page to page. That can generate a fair amount of code noise. What do you do to work around that?

Comment: Depending on the amount of data that has to be passed back and forth, I typically keep it stored in Sessions. If it's too much, then I'll make a trip to the database and fetch it again.

Answer (score 1):

You've broken a wall that most software developers have, the one that was blocking your view on usability before. A lot of developers don't really think about it and try to make it easier for them by stuffing functionality in one window, web page or whatever.

The thing is once you start designing software from the user's point of view, i.e. making it easier, several things start to become clear. One is the issue of code maintenance, that code is easily more managable to work on if you don't stuff everything in one giant class or whatever travesty you've been doing. The other is usability itself, that you start to think how the user is actually using your application through the graphical interface. Third is avoiding requirements or scope creep where you stop developing functionality that the user doesn't need.

We as users want simplicity partly because we don't want to spend most of our time muddling through a bad UI when we can get our work done faster with a simple and slick UI. That makes it for us software developers the right thing to do, to think through your design on all levels... that and **specs always lie**.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely agree: most attempts at writing pages/forms that do too much have resulted in

- bugs and rewrites. Problems occur with keeping all parts valid/synchronized,
- excess managing of users' expectations ("*I've entered a bill number here and clicked "find person" there but it gives an error message. Why?*") when the two are logically separate. These questions cannot arise if only the valid options are visible,
- Formatting/layout issues: In ASP.NET pages, trying to layout independent User Controls turns out to be a nightmare ("*But we really want all the buttons vertically aligned!*" in separate user controls. Good luck with that.)

I'd consider webpages with more than one functionality only if the target audience consists of domain experts, i.e. people that need lots of functionality on one page for better productivity (think data-entry or financial software with lots of variables).

Even then, most of the time, it's possible separate pages into single units.

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. Yes - me
3. I found the happy medium was to use Masterpages, and using it in a way that was familiar to IFrames. That I could have a lots of functionality combined well together. There is a more interesting way of doing this with WPF/Silverlight called [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The amount of functionality on a page is usually not determined by you but by your customer. If the customer demands a single page to update some `VeryComplexObject`, you're likely to end up with an aspx page that has a significant number of lines. Main reason is that you simply have a lot of event handlers for all actions on the page.

Whether that page is complex is entirely up to you. You should always attempt to make your code-behind file as simple and clean as possible. Some suggestions in that direction:

- Move all business code to another application layer.
- Use `ObjectDataSource` for providing data to data-bound controls such as `ListView`, `GridView`, `Repeater`, ... Delegating loading of data to a dedicated object prevents a lot of overhead in your aspx.cs file.

Another suggestion is to use user controls to implement portions of your page. You would usually only do this when you can reuse the user control, but it can also be of great help reducing page complexity (both of your code-behind file as well as your aspx).

Comment: From my stand point, the "customers" don't have specific design requirements. They generalize and I have to figure it all out. That's why I have to determine what goes where among the pages.

Comment: I agree with Ronnie on this one, the customer knows what their end goal is but is our job to make the implemntation as simple to use as possible. Having said that the UI sometimes needs to be more complex but that all depends on the job at hand and the type of person using it.

Comment: In that case I would first create an html mockup for your web site to show the customer what it's going to look like. Involve them as early as possible. You do not want to build a site only to have your customer say: 'that's not what we wanted'.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I think we are all guilty of forgetting just who it is that we develop our applications for. It isn't always easy as a developer to be able to take a step back and have a look at your application as a user might do so. This is why big companies employee hundreds of people to do this for them and they don't always get it right.

Usability is a massive subject but it is defiantly something that all developers need to keep in mind. It has taken me a long time to learn this but when tackling any development task I always try to think about how my users are going to interact with what I am writing. This will make a difference to all levels of your development.

I would suggest reading [Don't Make Me Think by Steve Krug](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Make-Me-Think-Usability/dp/0321344758/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1237554327&sr=8-1). This book won't take you an age to read and it puts across some fantastic ideas that can help you to develop applications that are much easier to use and understand.

I always find that once I have thought about the user experience the decisions about what my web pages are going to do and how they are going to interact are much easier to make.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should ask the people who are using your site.  Or better yet, just watch people use your site.  I think that would tell you if your site is designed well, or if you need to change it.